# IE8 doesn't retain my spaces between the string

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I build a selectbox through javascript and append to a div element as an innerhtml
The text value for the options has 2 spaces in between the string value. I do a string comparison to set the selected value which fails only in IE8 because it strips out one white space in between.
Below is the demo html and script which describes my issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function buildSelect() {
            $('#mydiv').html('<select id="listOption1" name="listOption1"><option value="1234">30.0  x 80.0 in</option><option value="12345">32.0  x 80.0 in</option><option value="123">36  x 80 in</option></select>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="buildSelect()">
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In all the other browsers, the 2 spaces (32.0  x 80.0 in) between the string is retained including IE9.In IE8 it doesn't retain those.
Can anyone suggest a solution how to have that space retained in IE8?

Comment: perhaps if you'd use &nbsp; ?

Comment: is there some significance in needing more than once consecutive space?

Comment: This is actually some data which i have received from API.Extra spaces might be added for readbility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `&nbsp;` to insert non-breaking spaces or the `white-space` css property:

```
white-space: pre;
```

`pre` preserves whitespace without wrapping, `pre-wrap` will wrap text where necessary.

This requires a valid DOCTYPE in IE8, which should always be present anyway.

Comment: I have added white-space:pre for the select and for the option element.Still the issue exists in IE8

Comment: Looks like an issue with these being select/options. You may have to resort to using `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to add the spaces for legibility reasons? Replace all the spaces where you are adding double spaces with `&nbsp;` This will provide consistency across all browsers, including IE